# ../manage.py makemessages -l zh_CN do not create file

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am using Django for a web app.Today I used command:

```
../manage.py makemessages -l zh_CN
```

to create the .po file.But nothing hanppend without printing the

`processing locale zh_CN`

Why?In my settins.py,all things about I18N was set.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-hans'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)
```

Does anyone know how to deal？
Many thanks
And

`django-admin makemessages -l zh_CN`

is still the same result.
My app is 'enterprise' and 'myauth'.
My directories structure is:

```
.
├── Web
├── captcha
├── collected_static
├── demo
├── dict
├── enterprise
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── templatetags
│   └── view
├── locale
├── logs
├── myauth
│   ├── form
│   ├── locale
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
├── static
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── d3
│   ├── img
│   ├── jquery
│   └── nvd3
└── templates
```

Comment: Which directory are you running this command? What is your project directories structure?

Comment: What django version are you using? Your language code suggests 1.9 but your `LOCALE_PATHS` suggest < 1.8

Comment: @kia I run this command in the root directory and the 'myauth' directory

Comment: @Sayse Version of my Django is 1.8.4

Comment: In which case your language code is wrong and that should also be `zh-CN` but I don't think that would solve your issue, have you actually got strings in `trans` tags etc?

Comment: Do you think that the problem is because of your `locale` name? The `locale` parameter of `makemessages` command is not the point for this problem. You can run `makemessages -l anything` so there will be directory with `anything` name.

Comment: @kia I ran `django-admin makemessages -l abcdefg`.Then I used `locate abcdefg`. Nothing was found................